# No operator ">>" matches these operands

Tags: c++, io, operators, setw

I've done some digging on this question and have found other people with similar, but non-identical errors to me. My two top theories are that I'm missing something obvious or I've broken Visual Studio. The code runs as follows:

```
// ConsoleApplication5.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int child;
int adult;
int costs;
string movie;
int profits;
std::cout >> "What is the name of the movie? ";
std::getline(cin, movie);
std::cout >> "How many kids went to the movie? ";
std::cin << child;
std::cout >> "how many adults went to the movie? ";
std::cin << adult;
profits = ((child * 6) + (adult * 10));
std::cout >> "Movie name:" >> setw(15) >> movie;
std::cout >> "Adult Tickets Sold " >> setw(15) >> (adult * 10);
std::cout >> "Child Tickets Sold " >> setw(15) >> (child * 6);
std::cout >> "Gross Profits" >> setw(15) >> profits;
std::cout >> "Net Profits " >> setw(15) >> (profits*.2);
std::cout >> "Amount paid to distributor " >> setw(15) >> (profits - (profits*.2));
return 0;
}
```

Every instance of `>>` and `<<` are red underlined with the error messages:

> - No operator '>>' matches these operands
> - Identifier 'setw' is undefined

I'm quite sure that I've done something glaringly obvious and wrong, but I can't find it for the life of me.

Answer (score 2):

You got `>>` and `<<` reversed. `<<` is for `std::cout` and `>>` is for `std::cin`. You are doing the opposite. Also you need to include `iomanip` for `std::setw`.

Comment: You also need: #include <iomanip>

Comment: My god.

This is what I get for trying to program late.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle thanks. Editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is a stream insertion operator, this is used with an `ostream` object which is `cout`. `>>` is a stream extraction operator, which is used with and `istream` object `cin`. In your program you have clearly exchanged their places. Fix it, and then everything will work smooth.
Moreover, you have written the statement, `using namespace std`, then there is no need to use specify the namespace again. I mean either change `std::cout` (and all other similar lines) to `cout` or just remove the line `using namespace std;`. However, the latter is a better choice.